# using where not exists for retrieve records that are not in users documents

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that retrieves documents users have assigned to them. 
There are some users who are missing some documents
i would like to retrieve what documents do not exist in the application where the users need to have these docs completed. 
The following is my query
I am stuck on the where not exists part. this query does not return any records and i know some of these users do not have this document

```
SELECT  T.PRAC_ID, T.Document_ID, T.DocumentName, S.DOC_ID FROM
   **#TMP_PRCS T-- this is the table that contains the doucments the users have** LEFT OUTER JOIN
   **#tmp_doclookup S -- this is the doc look up table that contains userid and doc id.** ON T.PRAC_ID = S.PRAC_ID WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT DOC_ID  FROM #TMP_PRCS L WHERE S.PRAC_ID = L.prac_id) ORDER
   BY  PRAC_ID, DOCUMENT_ID
```

Comment: https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` is turning you left join into an inner join. Add that condition to the join's `ON` clause instead.

```
select T.PRAC_ID,
    T.Document_ID,
    T.DocumentName,
    S.DOC_ID
from #TMP_PRCS T
left outer join #tmp_doclookup S on T.PRAC_ID = S.PRAC_ID
    and not exists (    -- Use "and" here instead of "where"
        select DOC_ID
        from #TMP_PRCS L
        where S.PRAC_ID = L.prac_id
        )
order by PRAC_ID,
    DOCUMENT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all available documents (S) then left join to the documents the user already has (T). All the fields from T will be null if the user does not have the document.

```
SELECT T.PRAC_ID, T.Document_ID, T.DocumentName, S.DOC_ID FROM 
#tmp_doclookup S -- this is the doc look up table that contains userid and doc id. 
LEFT JOIN #TMP_PRCS T -- this is the table that contains the doucments the users have 
ON T.PRAC_ID = S.PRAC_ID WHERE T.PRAC_ID IS NULL
```